# SQL Pivot only select rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I am attempting to pivot a database so that only certain rows become columns.  Below is what my table looks like:

```
ID  QType       CharV       NumV
1   AccNum                  10
1   EmpNam      John Inc    0
1   UW          Josh        0
2   AccNum                  11
2   EmpNam      CBS         0
2   UW          Dan         0
```

I would like the table to look like this:

```
ID  AccNum      EmpNam
1   10          John Inc
2   11          CBS
```

I have two main problems I am trying to account for.

1st: the value that I am trying to get isn't always in the same column.  So while AccNum is always in the NumV column, EmpName is always in the CharV column.

2nd: I need to find a way to ignore data that I don't want.  In this example it would be the row with UW in the QType column.

Below is the code that I have:

```
SELECT *
  FROM testTable
    Pivot(
    MAX(NumV)
    FOR[QType]
    In ([AccNum],[TheValue])
    )p
```

But it's giving me the below result:

```
ID  CharV   AccNum  TheValue
1           10      NULL
2           11      NULL
2   CBS     NULL    NULL
2   Dan     NULL    NULL
1   John IncNULL    NULL
1   Josh    NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case grouping with conditional aggregation should work. Try something like:

```
SELECT ID
, MAX(CASE WHEN QType = 'AccNum' THEN NumV END) AS AccNum
, MAX(CASE WHEN QType = 'EmpNam' THEN CharV END) AS EmpNam
FROM testTable
GROUP BY ID
```

Since the inner CASE only gets a value when the WHEN condition is met, the MAX function will give you the value desired. This of course, only works as long as there are only unique QTypes per ID.

Generally using PIVOT in Sql-Server doesn't work in one step when your conditions are complex, specially when you need values from different columns. You could pivot your table in two queries and join those, but it would perform poorly and is less readable than my suggestion.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly!  I appreciate you giving me the easiest and simplest answer and not what I thought I wanted.